# MySQL optimized query

Tags: mysql

Now I came across an issue, I have table as below:

```
Task Id       StudentId    Marks
  1                1         12
  1                2         15              
  1                3         17
  2                1         15 
  2                3         20
  3                1         8 
  3                3         5         
  3                5         17
```

I was required to get a lists of studentid who has max and marks in each task. So the required output is:

TaskId               StudentId      Marks

```
 1                    3            17
 2                    3            20
 3                    5            17
```

Now I created a temporary table to store max.marks of each task.

TaskId  Max.Marks

```
 1     17
 2     20
 3     17
```

Then I joined the temporary table to the main table and fetched the row with marks equal to max.marks of that task.

Can anyone suggest a better query without any sub-queries and temporary table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of temporary table, use a subquery (a derived table), then join it to the original marks table:

```
SELECT
    t.TaskId, t.StudentId, t.Marks 
FROM
        tableX AS t
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT 
              TaskID
            , MAX(Marks) AS MaxMarks
          FROM 
              tableX
          GROUP BY
              TaskID
        ) AS m
            ON  m.TaskId = t.TaskId
            AND m.MaxMarks = t.Marks ;
```

If you have an index on `(TaskId, Marks, StudentId)`, it will help efficiency.

You can also use this variation:

```
SELECT
    t.TaskId, t.StudentId, t.Marks 
FROM
        ( SELECT DISTINCT
              TaskId
          FROM
              tableX
        ) AS dt
    JOIN 
        tableX AS t
            ON  t.TaskId = dt.TaskId
            AND t.Marks = 
                ( SELECT 
                      tm.Marks 
                  FROM 
                      tableX AS tm
                  WHERE
                      tm.TaskId = dt.TaskId
                  ORDER BY 
                      tm.Marks DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                ) ;
```

Comment: +1 for your  answer, but he specifically asked for one without subqueries.  I'm not sure that's possible. I am removing my answer, since i misread the question.

Comment: @Aaron: I don't think this can be done without subqueries of some kind. (perhaps with triggers that update another table that holds these rseults). And I don't really see any reason for not using subqueries - unless it's a theoretical question.

Comment: I agree, I was only pointing out the poster's requirement.

Comment: hi guys thanks for the comments..but..i used the temporary table bcos..i think..it is more efficient then using subqueries..am i wrong??

Comment: @matang: Did you test/measure performance?

Comment: @ypercube no i did not for this specific query..but yes i have measured for my many other queries where i gained more performance because of the joins with temp. table instead of the sub queries like wise "IN()"

Comment: `column IN (SELECT ... FROM ...)` is known to not perform optimally in MySQL. But there are ways to rewrite such queries. And the cost of creating temporary and adding index has to be taken into account.

Comment: Not that I reject temporary tables, but my first try on optimizing a query is indexing and rewriting.